# How do i know whether the page has been preloaded successfully in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have three main pages in the project, they are `HomePage`, `AboutPage` and `ContactPage`. And I turned the `preloadModules` on to preload these pages. I want the app to pop a message once pages are preloaded successfully. But I don't know how to do it, and I didn't see any lifecycle event regarding the preloading.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have much experience with this, but if you're just testing, you could use `console.log` to see in the console when it has preloaded.

Comment: @JAW Thank you very much for the quick reply. But the problem is I don't know where to put `console.log` in. Take AboutPage for example, if there is a lifecycle event called "isPreloaded", I can put `console.log` in it, but there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

On all 3 pages use

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.event.publish('pageLoaded');
}
```

On app.component.ts in constructor after device ready

`//create variable pagesLoaded = 0;`

```
this.event.subscribe('pageLoaded', ()=> {
   if (++this.pagesLoaded > 2) console.log('3 pages are loaded');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I tried your code, and I received the message said "3 pages are loaded" when I finished visiting all three pages. But I would like to see the message when all three pages preloaded without visiting them. I believe the problem is `ionViewDidLoad()` will only be triggered when I'm entering the page, and I'm looking for something like `ionViewDidPreload()`.

Comment: Hm, not sure what you are exactly referring to. What are you trying to achieve by preloading pages?